# Update clause with having count(*)

Tags: sql, ignite

I have this query that shows the protocols and status of the protocols where there is just one participant on it and it the protocol is opened:

```
SELECT a.protocol_number, b.STATUS_NAME, COUNT(*) FROM PARTICIPANTS a LEFT JOIN PROTOCOLS b ON a.PROTOCOL_NUMBER = b.PROTOCOL_NUMBER GROUP BY a.PROTOCOL_NUMBER, b.STATUS_NAME HAVING count(*) = 1 AND b.STATUS_NAME = 'OPEN';
```

I would like to update the status of these protocols to CLOSED, but I am not finding a query that runs ok. Tried this one but it hangs forever:

```
UPDATE
    PROTOCOLS p1
SET
    p1.STATUS_NAME = 'CLOSED'
WHERE
    p1.protocol_Number IN (
    SELECT
        PROTOCOL_NUMBER
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            a.protocol_number, b.STATUS_NAME, COUNT(*)
        FROM
            PARTICIPANTS a
        LEFT JOIN PROTOCOLS b ON
            a.PROTOCOL_NUMBER = b.PROTOCOL_NUMBER
        GROUP BY
            a.PROTOCOL_NUMBER, b.STATUS_NAME
        HAVING
            count(*) = 1
            AND b.STATUS_NAME = 'OPEN');
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: if the table is huge and under heavy insert/update load, your query may hang for a long time (due to transactions). try to execute it when the table is not busy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your update query, you don't need to join again the protocol table inside the sub query and using exists we can correlate it from the outer one.

Assuming you have index present for `protocol_number` following should do the work. Could you try with below,

```
update protocols p1
   set p1.status_name = 'CLOSED'
 where p1.status_name = 'OPEN'
   and exists (select 1
                 from participants a
                where a.protocol_number = b.protocol_number
                group by a.protocol_number
                having count(*) = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be faster and semantically equivalent on the assumption that STATUS_NAME 'OPEN' is assigned only once to a `PROTOCOL_NUMBER`.

```
UPDATE
    PROTOCOLS p1
SET
    p1.STATUS_NAME = 'CLOSED'
WHERE
    STATUS_NAME = 'OPEN'
    and not exists (select null
                from protocols p2
                where p2.PROTOCOL_NUMBER = p1.PROTOCOL_NUMBER
                 and b.STATUS_NAME <> 'OPEN');
```